# How can I make the text inside my <h2> appear in the center

Tags: html, css

I am using an `<h2>` tag.  The title appears left justified.  How can I make the text appear in the center of the `<h2>` ?

Comment: Using `text-align: center` should work but if you are using float or display: inline/inline-block properties then you need to use `margin: 0 auto` or give `width: 100%` and then `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CSS `text-align` property:

```
text-align: center;
```

Other values for this property include `left`, `right` and `justify`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
h2{
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: An `h2` defaults to `display: block` which means your `width: 100%` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Css , use `text-align:center` to the particular tag `<h2>`

### **Example**

**html**

```
<h2 class="aligncenter">Welcome</h2>
```

**css**

```
.aligncenter{
    text-align: center;
}
```